# Plugin marker artifact for precompiled script plugin not configured automatically

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

The [example in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) assumes the plugin lives in the same project that uses it in the `buildSrc` folder,
however, I want to publish the plugin to an internal repository so that it can be used by other projects.
The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#java_gradle_plugin) for Java-based Gradle plugins states that applying the `java-gradle-plugin` will

> Configure the Maven or Ivy Publish Plugins publishing plugins to publish a Plugin Marker Artifact for each plugin.

This doesn't seem to be the case for `groovy-gradle-plugin`.
I managed to [manually create the marker](https://gist.github.com/asardaes/6abf1fede590257e3448e59fd0d0af2a),
but maybe I'm missing something? I'm using Gradle 6.6 and 6.7 across different repositories.

Comment: cf. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15190

Comment: Did you check out the following sample? In my case I'm able to import the generated plugin afterwards: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_publishing_convention_plugins.html

Comment: @hb0 I have updated to Gradle 7.2 and I still see the same behavior (marker missing and properties file has the wrong name). If anything, there's now an explicit [note in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#note_for_plugins_published_without_java_gradle_plugin).